# Java/Ruby: is there a way to do .constantize or Object.send() in Java?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

In Ruby, you can do `"var1".constantize` to get the actual variable `var1`.
Ruby also has Model.Send("method name, parameters can be here, etc"), and it would be the same as actually calling that method.

What I want to do.. is... kinda tricky... I want the string "var1 == var2" to be converted to actual variables in my java app, then evaluated.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [JRuby](http://jruby.org/)?

As to your questions:

1. There is no peer to constantize that will allow for an eval like syntax where you can pass in a String and convert it to code in Java.  You can do things like Class.forName to load a particular class from a String, but it doesn't sound that is what you are looking for.
2. You can use the Java reflection API to dynamically invoke methods on a class   Check out [Jakarta Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) for some utility methods that may help.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, similar behaviour is achieved through the Reflection API. However, since Java is a compiled language, local variables' (within methods, constructors, parameters, etc) information is erased on compilation.
However you still have complete access to class names, hierarchies, methods and fields (class variables).
A good starting point is the [Reflection API tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) or the getClass() method of Object.

Answer (score 0):

In Java if you want a dynamic lookup of variables, you would typically place them in a Map and lookup use the keys of that Map.

Can you explain what you are trying to do in more detail, I suspect what you are trying to do can be done simply a different way in Java.